# Calculate $\frac{∂L}{∂A}$ given $\frac{∂L}{∂G}$, $D=(A-\iota\cdot B^T)\odot\iota\cdot C^T$, and $G=D \odot(\iota\cdot E^T)+\iota\cdot F^T$

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Using the matrixes:

$$A, D, G \in \mathbb{R}_{N \times M}$$

$$\iota = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
⋮\\
1
\end{bmatrix}_{N \times 1}$$

$$B, C, E, F \in \mathbb{R}_{M \times 1}$$

I want to calculate the derivatives of the following equations:

$$
D = (A - \iota \cdot B^T) \odot \iota \cdot C^T \\
G = D \odot (\iota \cdot E^T) + \iota \cdot F^T
$$

Where $\cdot$ is dot product, and $\odot$ is element wise multiply.

My understanding is that these are all the possible partial derivatives:

$$
\frac{\partial D}{\partial A},
\frac{\partial D}{\partial \iota},
\frac{\partial D}{\partial B},
\frac{\partial D}{\partial C},
\frac{\partial G}{\partial D},
\frac{\partial G}{\partial \iota},
\frac{\partial G}{\partial E},
\frac{\partial G}{\partial F}
$$

Now, I am given $\frac{\partial L}{\partial G}$. I want to calculate these partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \iota},
\frac{\partial L}{\partial A},
\frac{\partial L}{\partial B},
\frac{\partial L}{\partial C},
\frac{\partial L}{\partial D},
\frac{\partial L}{\partial E},
\frac{\partial L}{\partial F}
$$
So far, I managed to get...

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial F} = \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial G} \right)^T \cdot \frac{\partial G}{\partial F}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial D} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial G} \odot \frac{\partial G}{\partial D}
$$

I think we can ignore $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \iota}$ because the values of $\iota$ are constant. But then I am immediately stuck on $\frac{\partial L}{\partial E}$ and the other components.

How do I solve for the remaining four partials --
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial A},
 \frac{\partial L}{\partial B},
 \frac{\partial L}{\partial C},
 \frac{\partial L}{\partial E}$ ?

Comment: Giving suggestions on what may be missing or pointing out gaps in my understanding are  appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\iota}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gg{\LR{\grad{\l}{G}}}
\def\ga{\LR{\grad{\l}{A}}}
$Let's use a convention wherein an uppercase letter denotes a matrix, a lowercase letter a vector, and a Greek letter a scalar. This means renaming the following problem variables
$$\big\{B,C,E,F\big\}\to \big\{b,c,e,f\big\}$$
because we'll need to use those uppercase letters to denote diagonal matrices whose main diagonals are the lowercase letters, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
B = \Diag{b},\quad C = \Diag{c},\quad E = \Diag{e},\quad I = \Diag{\o}  = {\it Identity\;Matrix}
}$$
Diagonal matrices can replace Hadamard products via the following rule
$$\eqalign{
M\odot\LR{b\cdot c^T} &= B\cdot M\cdot C \\
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
D &= {A\cdot C-\o\cdot b^T\cdot C} \\
G &= {D\cdot E-\o\cdot f^T} \\
}$$
Finally, let's use a colon to denote the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}
   \;=\; \trace{A\cdot B^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\tt1)$ it reduces to an ordinary dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a
product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{A\cdot B} &= \LR{C\cdot B^T}:A = \LR{A^T\cdot C}:B \\\\
}$$

---

Use the given gradient to write the differential of the function
in terms of $G$, then change the independent variable from
$G\to D\to A$, then recover the gradient wrt $A$.
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= \gg:dG \\
  &= \gg:\LR{dD\cdot E} \\
  &= \LR{\gg\cdot E}:{dD} \\
  &= \LR{\gg\cdot E}:\LR{dA\cdot C} \\
  &= \LR{\gg\cdot E\cdot C}:{dA} \\
\ga &= \gg\cdot E\cdot C
 \;\;\doteq\; \gg\odot\LR{\o\cdot e^T}\odot\LR{\o\cdot c^T} \\
}$$
The other gradients can be calculated in a similar fashion.

Comment: Note that $\iota \mathbf{e}^T \odot \iota\mathbf{c}^T $ simplifies into $\iota (\mathbf{e} \odot \mathbf{c})^T $

Comment: In other words, $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial G} \cdot \frac{\partial G}{\partial D} \cdot \frac{\partial D}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial G} \odot \frac{\partial G}{\partial D} \odot \frac{\partial D}{\partial A}$ ?

Comment: @Joseph $\def\q{\partial}
\def\fg#1#2{\frac{\q #1}{\q#2}}
$No, the product between the terms is neither the Hadamard $(\odot)$ product nor the dot $(\cdot)$ product, but the Frobenius $(:)$ product mentioned above, i.e. 
$$\fg LA ​= \fg LG:\fg GD:\fg DA$$
But the problem with this kind of expression is that $\fg GD$ and $\fg DA$ are fourth-order tensors, which are hard to manipulate using matrix notation, and hard to calculate correctly. The point of the _differential_ approach is that it uses only vector and matrix quantities, completely avoiding higher-order tensors.